Как прописать в названии файлов .png и .xlsx имена переменных?
Есть функция, в которую закладываются 2 переменные. Эти переменные - столбцы из большой таблицы.
def regr(x, y):
   x = acc[x] 
   y = acc[y]
   sns.regplot(x, y, line_kws=dict(color="r"))    
   plt.savefig('plot_' + ... + '.png')

   accc = pd.merge(x, y, left_index= True, right_index = True)
   accc.to_excel('table' + ... + '.xlsx') 

x & y - это числа от 1 до  2023.

Как при вызове regr(x,y) вывести картинку с именем типа "plot_x_y.png"?
Можно ли каким-то образом аналогично прописывать имена переменных в составе имени файла при выводе таблицы через pd.to_excel ?


def regr(x, y):
   acc_x = acc[x] 
   acc_y = acc[y]
   sns.regplot(acc_x, acc_y, line_kws=dict(color="r"))    
   plt.savefig(f'plot_{x}_{y}.png')

   accc = pd.merge(acc_x, acc_y, left_index= True, right_index = True)
   accc.to_excel(f'table_{x}_{y}.xlsx')


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

попробуйте форматированные строки:
def regr(x, y):
   x = acc[x] 
   y = acc[y]
   sns.regplot(x, y, line_kws=dict(color="r"))    
   plt.savefig(f'plot_{x}_{y}.png')

   accc = pd.merge(x, y, left_index= True, right_index = True)
   accc.to_excel(f'table_{x}_{y}.xlsx')


Увы, такое не работает: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'plot_нет2018\n1       63.0\n2       73.0\n3       55.0\n4       39.0\n5       99.0\n       ...  \n824    211.0\n828    214.0\n829    108.0\n830    155.0\n831    183.0\nName: 1977, Length: 806, dtype: float64_нет2018\n1      114.0\n2      149.0\n3       94.0\n4      146.0\n5      162.0\n       ...  \n824    352.0\n828    173.0\n829    149.0\n830    166.0\n831    167.0\nName: 1, Length: 806, dtype: float64.png'

Придумал выделить имена столбцов в отдельные переменные и заработало:
def regr(x, y):
   x = acc[x]
   x_name = x.name
   y = acc[y]
   y_name = y.name
   ...
   plt.savefig(f'plot_{x_name}_{y_name}.png')
   

и xlsx аналогично!
